# Ejected React Native app cannot reach Firestore backend

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-native

I was using Firestore through the Firebase Javascript SDK in my react-native app using expo, but after ejecting from expo I get this error even though my device is connected to the internet:

```
@firebase/firestore: Firestore (7.19.1): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds.
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
```

How would I fix this, or should I just use the react-native-firebase package?

Comment: I am having the same issue.

Comment: @ColdCerberus try adding `firebase.firestore().settings({experimentalForceLongPolling: true})` to your firebase config.js

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this by adding this line at the bottom of my firebase config.js:

```
export const firebase = Firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.firestore().settings({experimentalForceLongPolling: true}); // add this
```

Now firestore works as expected for me